# webcomponents - hide dropdown menu on window.onclick

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

dropdown menu is created in shadowDOM

almost perfect, 
but the problem is how to hide the dropdown menu when click on any where else in window

```
class NavComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        let template = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('template');
        let clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
        let root = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        root.appendChild(clone);
    }


    connectedCallback() {
        let ddc = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.dropdowncontainer')
        let dd = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
        let ddc_length = ddc.length

        for (let index = 0; index < ddc_length; index++) {
            ddc[index].addEventListener('click', e => {
                dd[index].classList.toggle('show');
            });
        }

        /**   have to update the code ............ */
        window.onclick = function (event) {

        }  /**  END - have to update the code ............ */

    }
}

customElements.define('app-nav', NavComponent)
```

please refer this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xx3sUEEKWjvdzy7eYPMY?p=preview) for complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unrelated suggestion: you should probably separate `.dropdown` into its own `<app-nav-dropdown>` component and assign the 'click' event listeners in its 'constructor' or 'connectedCallback'.

The best idea for your problem is to

```js
ddc[index].addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(dd[index].classList.contains('show')) {
        dd[index].classList.remove('show');
        window.removeEventListener('click', handleDropdownUnfocus, true);
    }
    else {
        dd[index].classList.add('show');
        window.addEventListener('click', handleDropdownUnfocus, true);
    }
});
```

*Note*: I use addEventListener with `true`, such that the event happens at capture, so that it's will not happen immediately after the .dropdown click handler.

And your `handleDropdownUnfocus` will look like

```js
function handleDropdownUnfocus(e) {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('app-nav')).forEach(function(appNav) {
        Array.from(appNav.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.dropdown')).forEach(function(dd) {
            dd.classList.remove('show');
        });
    });
    window.removeEventListener('click', handleDropdownUnfocus, true);
}
```

There's a problem with this solution though, that if you click on the menu item again after opening it, it will call both `.dropdown` and `window` handlers, and the net result will be that the dropdown will remain open. To fix that, you would *normally* add a check in `handleDropdownUnfocus`:

```js
if(e.target.closest('.dropdown')) return;
```

However, it **will not work**. Even when you click on `.dropdown`, your `e.target` will be `app-nav` element, due to Shadow DOM. Which makes it more difficult to do the toggling. I don't know how you'd address this issue, maybe you can come up with something fancy, or stop using Shadow DOM.

Also, your code has some **red flags**... For example, you use `let` keyword in your for-loop, which is fine. The support for `let` is very limited still, so you're more likely going to transpile. The transpiler will just change every `let` to `var`. However, if you use `var` in your loop, assigning the handlers in a loop like that **will not work anymore**, because `index` for every handler will refer to the last dropdown (because index will now be global within the function's context and not local for every loop instance).

Answer (score 3):

The best solution, as @guitarino suggested is to define a dropdown menu custom element.

When the menu is clicked, call a (first) event handler that will show/hide the menu, and also add/remove a (second) `dropdown` event handler on `window`.

At its turn, the (second) `dropdown` event handler will call the first event handler only if the action is outside the custom element itself.

```
connectedCallback()
{        
    //mousedown anywhere
    this.mouse_down = ev => !this.contains( ev.target ) && toggle_menu()

    //toggle menu and window listener 
    var toggle_menu = () => 
    {
        if ( this.classList.toggle( 'show' ) )
            window.addEventListener( 'mousedown', this.mouse_down )
        else
            window.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', this.mouse_down )
    }

    //click on menu
    this.addEventListener( 'click', toggle_menu )   
}
```

It works with or without Shadow DOM:

```js
customElements.define( 'drop-menu', class extends HTMLElement 
{
  constructor ()
  {
    super()
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open'} )
        .innerHTML = '<slot></slot>'
  }

  connectedCallback()
  {        
    //mousedown anywhere
    this.mouse_down = ev => !this.contains( ev.target ) && toggle_menu()
        
    //toggle menu and window listener 
    var toggle_menu = () => 
    {
      if ( this.classList.toggle( 'show' ) )
        window.addEventListener( 'mousedown', this.mouse_down )
      else
        window.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', this.mouse_down )
    }

    //click on menu
    this.addEventListener( 'click', toggle_menu )   
  }

  disconnectedCallback ()
  {
    this.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', this.mouse_down )
  }
} )
```

```css
drop-menu  {
    position: relative ;
    cursor: pointer ;
    display: inline-block ;
}

drop-menu > output {
    border: 1px solid #ccc ;
    padding: 2px 5px ;
}

drop-menu > ul {
    box-sizing: content-box ;
    position: absolute ;
    top: 2px ; left: 5px ;
    width: 200px;
    list-style: none ;
    border: 1px solid #ccc ;
    padding: 0 ;
    opacity: 0 ;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out ;
    background: white ;
    visibility: hidden ;
    z-index: 2 ;

}

drop-menu.show  > ul {
    opacity: 1 ;
    visibility: visible ;
}

drop-menu > ul > li {
    overflow: hidden ;
    transition: font 0.2s ease-in-out ;
    padding: 2px 5px ;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

drop-menu:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

drop-menu  ul li:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

drop-menu ul li span {
    float: right;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    background-color: #f03861;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .8rem;
}

drop-menu ul li:hover span {
    background-color: #ee204e;
}
```

```html
<drop-menu><output>Services</output>
  <ul>
    <li>Graphic desing</li>
    <li>web design</li>
    <li>app design</li>
    <li>theme</li>
  </ul>
</drop-menu>
<drop-menu><output>tutorial</output>
  <ul>
    <li>css <span>12 available</span></li>
    <li>php <span>10 available</span></li>
    <li>javascript <span>40 available</span></li>
    <li>html <span>20 available</span></li>
  </ul>
</drop-menu>
```