# Web Components - How to style an overlapping component - to look like a drop down

Tags: css, web-component

I am new to web components.

I am trying to create a web component that looks like a "drop down / select".

when the element is closed but visible (not expanded) I would like it to be presented on the screen in the regular flow of the web page. Under it is some text that is not part of the control.

When the control is expanded, The expanded part should cover (go above) the text that is displayed under the control.

In practice the text is being pushed down.
Changing the control's css places the visual part over the text that should be below it.

I would appreciate ideas how to address the issue of creating a control that one part of it should be in the "flow" of the web page and the other part should "float" above the web page and located in relation to the visual part.

The following code is the web component: `drop-down.html`

```
    <template id="drop-down">
    <style>
        .row {
            z-index: 5;
            position:relative;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .drop-down {
            z-index: 5;
            position: relative;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="drop-down">
        <div class="row">
            <button onclick="addListElement(this);">+</button>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter List Item">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template id="list-item">
    <div class="row">
        <button onclick="addListElement(this);">+</button>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter List Item">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    let ddTemplate = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#drop-down');
    let liTemplate = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#list-item');

    customElements.define('drop-down', class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super(); // always call super() first in the ctor.
            let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow( {mode: 'open'} );
            shadowRoot.appendChild( ddTemplate.content.cloneNode( true ));
        }
     });

    function addListElement( el ) {
        var parent = el.parentNode;
        parent.parentNode.appendChild(liTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
</script>
```

The html that tests it is the following: `testDropDown.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test Drop-Down</title>

        <link rel="import" href="./drop-down/drop-down.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <drop-down>My Drop Down</drop-down>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do<br/>
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim<br/>
        ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut<br/>
        aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in<br/>
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla<br/>
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in<br/>
        culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/44340132/4600982 or at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41218056/4600982

Comment: @Supersharp - Thanks, following the recommended example - changing the divs to ul and li and using the presented css did the job.

Comment: You're welcome. You can upvote the answer that helped :-)